# What is the "seed" in Weka's SimpleKMeans clusterer?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, k-means

I'm using Weka's SimpleKMeans clusterer on a set of data.

But I'm unsure what the seed value is, what it does or how it affects the data.

i.e. How does a higher or lower seed value affect the result as oppose to the default value of 10?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

Answer (score 7):

Seed is just a random numbers seed. Once seed is fixed, even a randomized algorithm behaves deterministically. KMeans is not deterministic, so if you want repeatable results - you fix a seed. However there is completely no relation between exact value of the seed and the results of KMeans clustering.

Comment: I'm still unsure what it means though? I read it's something to do with initiliaizing the clusters, but confused at to it's actual purpose.

Comment: @Wolff It basically means that as KMeans uses random numbers, if you always use the same seed, you will always get the same random numbers. Which in short means, if you do run KMeans over the same data twice, if both times you had the same seed, you will get exactly the same result. If you dont use the same seed, results will vary every time you run KMeans.

Comment: @Wolff - the **only** purpose of seeding is to make sure that you get the exact same result when you run this code many times on the exact same data. KMeans is randomized, and so could lead to many different results if you simply run it many times - this way you can "force it" to be repeatable.

Comment: Ok I see, I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: @lejlot, Will higher or lower seed value affect the result ??
why we should give seed = 7 or 3

Comment: @venkat - each seed can lead to different result, but there is no relation between actual **value** of the seed and results. They are numbers only due to the way random number generators are implemented, but you can (and should) be thinking about seeds in terms of categorical objects - some arbitrary entities, like elephant, apple etc. seed "2" is equally different from "3" as it is from "1231231", each seed value is just a unique identifier (or at least - for proper random number generator it should be like this).

Comment: Thank you very much @lejlot for this valuable answer. So if I set the seed for k fold CV to be 0 does this turn the algorithm to behave in a deterministic manner? like choose the folds as the instances ordered in the dataset (e.g. if the dataset size is 100 the first 10 instances will be the first fold)?

Comment: @F505 If the seed is fixed, algorithm should be deterministic. How it will behave depends of course on the way it is implemented. I would not expect "0" to mean anything special (like first 10 instances going to one batch) though. Rather some arbitrary (but fixed) selection