# how to set Spark Kmeans initial centers

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using Spark ML for run Kmeans. I have bunch of data and three existing centers, for example the three centers are:`[1.0,1.0,1.0],[5.0,5.0,5.0],[9.0,9.0,9.0].` 
So how can I indicate the Kmeans centers are the above three vectors. 
I saw Kmean object has seed parameter, but the seed parameter is an long type not an array. So how can I tell Spark Kmeans to only use the existing centers for clustering.

Or say, I didn't understand what does seed mean in Spark Kmeans, I suppose the seeds should be an array of vectors which represents the specified centers before running clustering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, `seed` does not mean what you think, i.e. it is not used for 'seeding' (initializing) the cluster centers, but simply for setting the random seed - you can confirm this in the documentation for the [Scala](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans) and [Python](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans.seed) APIs.

To the best of my knowledge, there is currently (Spark 2.1) no way for supplying initial cluster centers for k-means in Spark ML (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426240/how-to-initialize-cluster-centers-for-k-means-in-spark-mllib) for Spark MLlib). The [`initMode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans.initMode) parameter, according to the documentation:

> can be either "random" to choose random points as initial cluster centers, or "k-means||" to use a parallel variant of k-means++')

Comment: Thanks, usually how to set the seed number please? a smaller value or a very larger value?

Comment: @Jack it doesn't matter; it is not affecting the performance, you need to set it explicitly only if you want your results to be exactly reproducible - have a look in this SO answer (or just google 'random seed') http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973817/what-is-the-seed-in-wekas-simplekmeans-clusterer