# Is it possible to initialize centers with specific values for spark kmeans?

Tags: pyspark, k-means, apache-spark-ml

I am using kmeans from sklearn and from pyspark.ml. 
The spark version is much faster. However, it doesn't seem have an option that I need. With sklearn kmeans I can specify an initial values for the cluster centers: KMeans(init=centers,...).
I don't see such an option for pyspark. Am I missing it, or am I out of luck and it doesn't exist?

Thank you

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483011/how-to-set-spark-kmeans-seeds/43483487#43483487

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set Spark Kmeans Seeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483011/how-to-set-spark-kmeans-seeds)

Comment: Thank you, desertnaut. Yes, indeed, it is the same question as my, albeit with a misleading title. I saw it and assumed it _is_ about setting the seed. So, I'll keep my question. Perhaps, there is some not-so-well known, even convoluted way to do it.

Comment: The question has been there since last April - if there was a way, most probably someone would have already provided it. And if the answer is helpful, upvotes are most welcome...

Comment: 4 years later and I can't believe there isn't still a way