# Reproducing K-means results in Spark ML

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I have an issue with reproducible results of clustering algorithms with Spark ML library.

I am using K-means clustering.

In K-means case, it is known that this issue can be handled by:

- fixing the initial cluster centers
- increasing the number of iterations

I have done the latter and I still get different results.

To do the first, I am lacking the SparkML's Kmeans functionality to enable the user to set custom cluster centers since there are only two options as it's mentioned in here [how to set Spark Kmeans initial centers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483011/how-to-set-spark-kmeans-initial-centers) : a) "random" and b) "kmeans//" for initialization of cluster centers.

Do you have any tips that could solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set Spark Kmeans initial centers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483011/how-to-set-spark-kmeans-initial-centers)

Comment: I have already checked out this thread. Yes, I am aware of this and actually wrote this in the question too. But I believe there is a way to initialize the centers maybe through extending spark ml clustering library?